# How to trigger lid close action programmatically?

Tags: macos, hardware, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

Is there a way to trigger the lid close action programmatically with a script or through terminal?

I am testing this by placing a small magnet near the SD slot on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: Does it have to be a "lid close action" specifically, or are you looking to programmatically put the machine to sleep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Apple supported programming interface to simulate the lid being closed.

You can put your Mac to [sleep using this command line](http://www.dssw.co.uk/sleepcentre/threads/terminal_command_to_sleep_mac.html):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to sleep'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was actually trying to get my mac to use external display as primary only. Upgrading to OSX Mavericks solved all my issues and it was free.

Comment: @louisinhongkong how did you get into clamshell mode without closing your laptop?! I'm on sierra

Answer (score 2):

You may put your machine to sleep with a shell script:

```
pmset sleepnow
```

P.S. If you intend to run this from a script, be prepared that machine won't sleep until script finishes, and if that's something like a daemon running in a loop, it won't ever work unless you run `pmset` in a subshell:

```
(pmset sleepnow &)
```